# Is there an R-way to set the plotly window height to 100% when working in a shiny Rmd?

Tags: html, r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

I am in the process of developing interactive reports with Rmd files, which specify a shiny runtime. I have, however, run into the following issue.

When plotlyfying ggplots that have larger height specifications, they start overlaying other aspects of the html output (e.g. in the exaple here its the text). So far my research has yielded that a fixed setting of `height == 400px` in the poltly container is responsible for this.

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(plotly) 
```

```{r}
fluidRow(
  column(3,
         selectInput("myselectorID",
                     "Select:",
                     selected = "setosa",
                     choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")))
)

renderPlotly({
  data <- iris %>% filter(Species == input[["myselectorID"]])
  ggp <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
  ggplotly(ggp, height = 487)
})
```
START
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
END
````

If I supply the following `css` (e.g. via the yaml header) then the problem is supposedly solved:

```css
.plotly {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

I would prefer a solution where I pass the parameter to R functions though. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Why would you prefer another solution? An R-side solution is unlikely because "100%" is a CSS unit (R does not know the size of the container)

Comment: I was told that using the `!important` tag is not super clean. Also, an R solution would allow me to control this per plot instead of having a blanket solution for everything that counts as `.plotly`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72435447/18309711), you can programmatically insert `ggplotly` outputs of specified heights like this:

1. set one ore more **id**s at which to place the plot output with `insertUI` later:

```
uiOutput('some_plots')
```

2. render the output and insert it at the specified output id; specify plot height as an argument to `plotlyOutput()`:

Example (inserting three *ggplotly* outputs of different heights at *id* "some_plots"):

```
plot_heights = c(200, 150, 350)

for(plot_index in 1:3){
  plot_name = paste0('plot_', plot_index)
  my_plot <- qplot(data = iris,
                   x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
                   geom = 'point') %>% ggplotly()

  output[[plot_name]] <- renderPlotly(my_plot) ## add to output list
  
  insertUI(selector = "#some_plots",
           where = "afterEnd",
           ui = plotlyOutput(plot_name,
                             ## specify plot height:
                             height = paste0(plot_heights[plot_index],'px')
                             )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered this and deleted their answer which was working... Not sure why but here's what they posted for the record since it seemed to do the trick:

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(plotly) 
```

```{r}
fluidRow(
  column(3,
         selectInput("myselectorID",
                     "Select:",
                     selected = "setosa",
                     choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")))
)

# create a specific plotly output with the parameter set as desired
plotlyOutput("testplot", height = "100%")

# address the plotly output
output$testplot <- renderPlotly({
  data <- iris %>% filter(Species == input[["myselectorID"]])
  ggp <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point()
  ggplotly(ggp, height = 487)
})
```
START
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
END
````

Comment: I deleted my earlier post when I noticed the height specification was still drawn from the `ggplotly( ..., height = 487)` argument. This *can* be omitted *if* the height is defined in `plotlyOutput( ... )` **and** in absolute units. Otherwise the page element will collapse to zero height. So, if absolute values are OK, that'd be a solution.

Comment: Assuming you wanted to wrap  this code (i.e. the code in the 2nd R chunk) into a function (ultimately that is my goal), how would you go about that? It does not seem to work out of the box.

Comment: Please see (now undeleted) answer for programmatically creating "anchor-IDs" and inserting one or more rendered *plotly* outputs at this/these IDs. Slightly off-topic: for setting variable values at another production stage, using Rmd together with **papermill** might come in handy: https://papermill.io/